# Meaning interpretation in the given context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Let us say there is a statement which says that a person joins a party two days earlier than me. In these type of cases I have too much confusion about when the person will join. Is the difference in days between the two persons equal to 1 or is it 2? A similar variation to the statement is there are two boxes above a blue box. Then is that particular box third or second from the blue box?

Comment: If they joined 0 days earlier, it’d have to be the same day. Now work backwards.

Comment: I think I am in the minority who would use "first from last" to mean what is the definition of "second from last", i.e., the next to last item. For me the "second from/to last" is the one after the "first from last". Welcome to my idiolect.  (I see this has been discussed in other questions.)

Comment: 'He joined two days earlier than I did' is usually rounded treating days as indivisible units when interpreted. It could even be that he joined at 23:59 on Monday and I joined at 00:01 on Wednesday, but we'd normally say 'two days earlier' rather than 1.00002315 days or 1 day earlier. // Also, last / next to last / second from last / ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I also say *last / next to last / second from last* but [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/second_to_last) has "Penultimate, next to last, immediately preceding the end of a sequence or list." for *second to/from last*.  Same for [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second%20to%20last)

Comment: A related topic: [fencepost errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).